# Help finding a chazal, could be עין יעקב

Tags: talmud-gemara, women, mussar-ethics, men-male, agada-stories-legends

I was asked to find a *maamar Chazal* that contrasts the *Gaava* (haughtiness) a woman can have with that of a male *talmid chochom*. I am unclear which way they differentiate, i was told there's something to do with דבורה הנביאה. This is all the info I have....I was told it was from *Ain Yaakov*.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501)

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 3):

The Gemora Megilla 14b says that a woman should not prophesize  when there is a greater, male Profit around. This was specifically in reference to Chulda the prophetess in the presence of Yirmiya:

> חולדה דכתיב (מלכים ב כב, יד) וילך חלקיהו הכהן ואחיקם ועכבור וגו' ובמקום דקאי ירמיה היכי מתנביא איהי אמרי בי רב משמיה דרב חולדה קרובת ירמיה היתה ולא הוה מקפיד עליה
>   Huldah was a prophetess, as it is written: “So Hilkiah the priest and Ahikam and Achbor and Shaphan and Asaiah went to Huldah the prophetess” (II Kings 22:14) as emissaries of King Josiah. But if Jeremiah was found there, how could she prophesy? Out of respect for Jeremiah, who was her superior, it would have been fitting that she not prophesy in his presence. The Sages of the school of Rav answered in the name of Rav: Huldah was a close relative of Jeremiah, and he did not object to her.

The Gemora goes on to say that the very names of Chulda and Devora were to connote humility like the lowly creatures the bee (Devora) and the weasel (Chulda) but that they did not act like intended rather with *Gaava*:

> אמר רב נחמן לא יאה יהירותא לנשי תרתי נשי יהירן הויין וסניין שמייהו חדא שמה זיבורתא וחדא שמה כרכושתא זיבורתא כתיב בה (שופטים ד, ו) ותשלח ותקרא לברק ואילו איהי לא אזלה לגביה כרכושתא כתיב בה (מלכים ב כב, טו) אמרו לאיש ולא אמרה אמרו למלך
>   Rav Naḥman said: Haughtiness is not befitting a woman. There were two haughty women, whose names were identical to the names of loathsome creatures. One, Deborah, was called a bee and one, Huldah, was called a weasel. From where is it known that they were haughty? With regard to Deborah it is written: “And she sent and called Barak” (Judges 4:6), but she herself did not go to him. And with regard to Huldah it is written: “Say to the man that sent you to me” (II Kings 22:15), but she did not say: Say to the king.